# ERROR - Missing string - jQuery Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

I´m using the [jQuery Typeahead plugin](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/), but if I´m trying to set up initial data, an error occurs and the input´s value is `false`.

Here is my configuration:

```
var typeaheadOptions = {
        dynamic: true,
        display: ['title'],
        template: '<span>{{title}}</span>',
        cache: true,
        debug: true,
        multiselect: {
            matchOn: ['id'],
            data: [{title: 'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}],
            callback: {
                onCancel: function(node, item) {removeItem(item)}
            }
        },
        source: {
            posts: {
                ajax: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: remoteURL,
                    data: {search: '{{query}}'}
                }
            }
        },
        callback: {
            onClick: function(node, a, item) {addItem(item)}
        }
    };
```

And here is the error:

```
ERROR - Missing string": {
  arguments: "",
  function: "helper.namespace()",
  message: "ERROR - Missing string",
  node: "#media-kit-post"
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Wrong item title]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Whats the format of the data you return from `remoteURL`?

Comment: A similar to which is in the `multiselect.data` property. `[{title: 'some title'}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share it with all of you:

The items in an initial `data` array need an additional key-value-pair: `matchedKey: 'title'`.

So here is my working `options` object:

```
var typeaheadOptions = {
        dynamic: true,
        display: ['title'],
        template: '<span>{{title}}</span>',
        cache: true,
        debug: true,
        multiselect: {
            matchOn: ['id'],
            data: [{title: 'title1', matchedKey: 'title'}, {title: 'title2', matchedKey: 'title'}],
            callback: {
                onCancel: function(node, item) {removeItem(item)}
            }
        },
        source: {
            posts: {
                ajax: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: remoteURL,
                    data: {search: '{{query}}'}
                }
            }
        },
        callback: {
            onClick: function(node, a, item) {addItem(item)}
        }
    };
```

The additional key-value-pair is indeed in the example for `multiselect` in the [typeahead documentation](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/), however not described in the surrounding text.